# A question on a generalization of perfect numbers

Tags: number-theory, group-theory

First of all, I would like to call a group immaculate provided that the orders of $G$ and $\Sigma$ (the order of $N$) where $N$ varies over all normal subgroups of $G$, are equal. From [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0104012v1) it has been said that *any abelianizer of a group whose order is less than that of $D(G)$, where $D(G)$ is the latter function defined above, is cyclic.*

Then my question is: Is there any characterization of groups $G$ such that $G^{ab}$ is an *imamculate group* where $G^{ab}$ is the abelianizer of $G$ which coincides with the previous one in the case that $G$ is a cyclic group of the order a perfect number.

This may be referenced to [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54851/is-there-an-odd-order-group-whose-order-is-the-sum-of-the-orders-of-the-proper-no), in any case, thanks.

Comment: Maybe call them immaculate groups, like in this MO question: http://goo.gl/Ez8XZ

Comment: Thanks, I just cannot find that post again. And this question obviously originates from the proof of the examples given in the link.

Comment: The fact that non-cyclic p-groups cannot be immaculate immediately implies non-cyclic nilpotent groups cannot be immaculate.

Comment: Well, @Steve D, can you be more specific, please, thanks.